# Could anyone answer me some questions on the method of bisection, please?

Tags: calculus

In my math textbook the subjects are presented as a few examples (from 6 to 11 or 12 usually) and the more than $50$ exercises at the end. So one of those examples was about the method of bisection and I didn't understand well enough, I have some doubts. The example reads: Find a solution of the equation $x^5-x=3$ in $(0,2$) to within an accuracy of 0.1 by repeatedly dividing intervals in half and testing each half for a root.

And in the solution it solves the equation for 1 and 2. Did it solve for $1$ and $2$ because they're in $(0,2)$? Could it have picked a number greater than $2$?
I'm working on an exercise and I need to understand how this method works. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x^5-x=3$

The question has told you there is an $x$ bigger than $0$ and less than $2$ for which $x^5-x=3$. Your task is to find that root to a suitable level of accuracy.

First plug in $x=0$. We get $0^5-0=0$

Then plug in $x=2$. We get $2^5-2=30$

Now plug in $x=1$, the midpoint of these two values. We get $1^5-1=0$.

Note that the answer we want $(3)$ lies between the results of $x=1$ and $x=2$. So we shrink our interval to $(1,2)$.

Now we plug in the midpoint of these two values, $x=1.5$. We get $1.5^5-1.5=6.09375$.

The answer we want $(3)$ is between $0$ and $6.09375$, so we now shrink our interval to between $x=1$ and $x=1.5$

Then use the midpoint of these $(x=1.25)$ and go from there...

Comment: So you can't choose x bigger than 3, right?

Comment: The question specifies you should start with $0$ and $2$, but either way, $2^5-2>3$, and therefore $3^5-3>3$ also, so there is no point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with values on both sides, i.e. with $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1^5-x_1\lt3$ and $x_2^5-x_2\gt3$, so that you can then narrow in on the root. The values should also be in the interval in which you want to find a root; otherwise the bisection might lead to a root outside the interval (since it can lead to any value that's between your initial values).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an equation, and an interval, and both of the following are fulfilled:

1. Both sides of the equation are defined and continuous for all $x$ on that interval
2. One side of the equation has greater value on one end of the interval, while the other side of the equation has greater value on the other end of the interval

Then the equation has (at least) one solution in that interval. And this is the case for your equation and interval. We want to narrow down the space of possible locations of that solution.

The idea of the bisection method  is the following: the middle of your interval is $x=1$, so we test the equation there. Now there are three possible cases:

1. The sides are equal. In that case we're done, as $x=1$ is a solution.
2. The side which is larger at $x=1$ is the side which is smaller at $x=2$. In that case, by the same reason as above, there most be a solution somewhere in $(1,2)$. Repeat this process, bisecting at $x=1.5$.
3. The side which is larger for $x=1$ is the side which is larger for $x=2$. In that case it is also the side which is smaller for $x=0$. By the same reason as above, there must be a solution somewhere in $(0,1)$. Repeat this process, bisecting at $x=0.5$.

There is no real reason to pick $x=2$ rather than $x=0$, but for the argument to work correctly, you have to pick *one* of the end points of your interval.